# Help in step of the proof of Burnside's $p^aq^b$ theorem (Doerk-Hawkes book)

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups

I'm reading the proof of the $p^aq^b$ Burnside's theorem from the book Finite soluble groups by Doerk and Hawkes. The fifth step of the proof says

> 2.5. Let $M$ and $H$ be maximal subgroups of $G$ (which btw is simple). Assume that $M$ has non-trivial normal $r$- and $s$- subgroups $R$ and $S$ respectively such that $R\times S\leq H$. Then
>
> - $R\times S\leq F(H)\leq M$ where $F(H)$ is the Fitting subgroup of $H$, and furthermore
> - M=H

The proof starts by saying

> Since $G$ is simple and $M$ is maximal, we have $N_G(R)=M=N_G(S)$, and therefore $S\unlhd C_H(R)$.

The first sentence is clear to me, the problem is, how do they conclude that $S\unlhd C_H(R)$?. Thanks.

Comment: Because $S \le C_H(R)  \le N_G(R) = N_G(S)$.

Comment: @DerekHolt could  you be more explicit, please?

Comment: @Jose What is the definition of $N_G(S)$? Write it down "in words" then you'll understand that Derek answered your question commpletely!

Comment: @M.U. wow! I finally got it! I feel so dumb now :)). Thanks.